# connecting begalbone via sockets

Tags: python, sockets, client

So I attempted to create a socket client with a begalbone to create a remote connection via python, i was using paramiko but a higher up wants me to use sockets instead.

I found a code that i was hoping would make this simple but it does not seem to function , my side is hung up at socket now listening and the begalbone side seems to have no feed back, here is the code I have so far.

my computer

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Aug 15 13:56:19 2022

@author: GigaGame
"""

import socket
import sys

HOST = ''
PORT = 20103

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. ')
        sys.exit()

print('Socket bind complete')

s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode('UTF-8')    # convert to string (Python 3 only)
        line = line.replace("\n","")   # remove newline character
        print( line )

s.close()
```

#begalbone side -----------------------------------------

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Aug 15 13:56:19 2022

@author: GigaGame
"""

import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC
import time
import socket
import sys

serverAddr = ('192.168.0.120', 20103)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(serverAddr)

fsr = 'P9_40'

ADC.setup()

while True:
        reading = ADC.read(fsr)*1000
        reading = int(round(reading))
        client.send((bytes(reading)))

client.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

lol so i had wrong ip to my computer, got socket open, thanks for the help me. now i just need to find a way to run the program and post it in the socket thingy interface.

Comment: since you just go tthe wrong IP address I'll vote to close this question as a typo